# Does Lombok's @UtilityClass support static imports? Are you sure it doesn't?

Tags: java, lombok

Lombok's doc says `@UtilityClass` doesn't provide support for static imports:

> Due to limitations in javac, currently non-star static imports cannot be used to import stuff from @UtilityClasses; don't static import, or use star imports.

However, I just checked, and it seems to work fine:

```java
@UtilityClass
public class AuthenticationUtils {
    public UUID getClientId(Authentication authentication) {
        return UUID.fromString(authentication.getName());
    }
}
```

```java
import static by.afinny.apigateway.util.AuthenticationUtils.getClientId;

// more annotations
@RestController
public class CreditCardController {
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<CreditCardDto>> getCreditCards(Authentication authentication) {
        return creditCardClient.getCreditCards(getClientId(authentication));
    }
```

```java
@WebMvcTest(CreditCardController.class)
class CreditCardControllerTest {
    // tests that pass
```

Was it fixed? Did the doc mean something else?

Comment: It's already explained here - https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2044. Please read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't support static imports indeed. To see that, try running `clean` and then `compile` (assuming it's a Maven project)

[image]